# Change color in java eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, text, colors, console

Is there any way to change text color in eclipse console?
I am not talking about when I go to options and change color from black to for example red.
I mean like when I launch my program and it executes code and at some point it changes color.
For example:

```
//code  
if (a == 2)  
//change text color to red and continue typing in red color
```

I am not talking about guis jframes etc. I am talking about Eclipse console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably by using a different [org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/console/MessageConsoleStream.html), considering that:

> It is ssed to write messages to a message console.
>   A message console may have more than one stream connected to it.
>   **Each stream may be displayed in a different color**

See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg43158.html):

> `IOConsoleOutputStream` has a `setColor(Color newColor)`, so I can `MessageConsole.getInputStream().setColor(Color newColor)` for each type of message.

Comment: I never knew about that :) Thnx

Comment: I am assuming this doesn't work if I execute the program from the console. Or am I wrong to assume this? If indeed I am right, then is there any other alternative(besides using a more cli oriented language)?