# Change color of java console output

Tags: java, colors, formatting, console

I was wondering if there is someway for me to set the color of the text that I output to the console in Java. It does not matter if it is system specific as the program will only be run on my Windows 7 x64 laptop.

This question: [Change color in java eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757311/change-color-in-java-eclipse-console) was asked several weeks ago and had a good solution(by @VonC) to a similar problem however it only addressed the issue inside eclipse.

Can the same effect be achieved if I execute my program from the command line? and if so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print color in console using System.out.println?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/how-to-print-color-in-console-using-system-out-println)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take a look at the Java Curses Library:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Here's an entry on how to use it:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html

Answer (score 9):

thy this....
furthermore read http://jansi.fusesource.org/

```
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
```

Comment: Don't forget to add usage: System.out.println( " This will be purple: " + PURPLE + "Purple!" + RESET + " normal color text" );

Answer (score 7):

Another library you may be interested in is Jansi: http://jansi.fusesource.org/

Jansi interprets ANSI code and format them for the console output. It works for both unix and windows.

*Update 11/2014:* you can also see the [github Page](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to Java console output, but if you're looking to use ANSI colors in Kotlin console output, this is a great library to use - https://github.com/importre/crayon

Comment: Ha - Kotlin hadn't been released yet when I asked this question! It would be announced 2 months later and I wouldn't actually learn of it until several years later.

Answer (score 1):

I needed colors for a project. Here is a class for everyone. Just do Colors.(color) + "whatever" to add color, bold, or italic. Use Colors.reset to reset the colors. Hope this helps.

```
package util;

public class Colors {
    public static final String reset = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String bold = "\u001b[1m";
    public static final String italic = "\u001b[3m";
    public static final String underline = "\u001b[4m";
    public static final String reversed = "\u001b[7m";
    public static final String black = "\u001b[30m";
    public static final String blue = "\u001b[34m";
    public static final String cyan = "\u001b[36m";
    public static final String green = "\u001b[32m";
    public static final String magenta = "\u001b[35m";
    public static final String red = "\u001b[31m";
    public static final String white = "\u001b[37m";
    public static final String yellow = "\u001b[33m";
    public static final String brightBlack = "\u001b[30;1m";
    public static final String brightBlue = "\u001b[34;1m";
    public static final String brightCyan = "\u001b[36;1m";
    public static final String brightGreen = "\u001b[32;1m";
    public static final String brightMagenta = "\u001b[35;1m";
    public static final String brightRed = "\u001b[31;1m";
    public static final String brightWhite = "\u001b[37;1m";
    public static final String brightYellow = "\u001b[33;1m";
    public static final String bgBlack = "\u001b[40m";
    public static final String bgBlue = "\u001b[44m";
    public static final String bgCyan = "\u001b[46m";
    public static final String bgGreen = "\u001b[42m";
    public static final String bgMagenta = "\u001b[45m";
    public static final String bgRed = "\u001b[41m";
    public static final String bgWhite = "\u001b[47m";
    public static final String bgYellow = "\u001b[43m";
    public static final String bgBrightBlack = "\u001b[40;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightBlue = "\u001b[44;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightCyan = "\u001b[46;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightGreen = "\u001b[42;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightMagenta = "\u001b[45;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightRed = "\u001b[41;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightWhite = "\u001b[47;1m";
    public static final String bgBrightYellow = "\u001b[43;1m";
}
```